Почему не сохраняются куки на хостинге (PHP)?
Не могу найти решение ошибки. После того, как загрузил сайт на хостинг, перестали работать куки, также перестали работать функции header(), и я полагаю, что какая-то проблема с HTTP-запросами. Сами значения кук неважны, любые куки не работают. Если что, то я опубликовал на 2 хостинга сразу, на хостинг сайта Timeweb и на хостинг сайта Beget.

Там вот где-то что-то не работает. Без подробностей ваш вопрос закроют.

Очевидная причина "навскидку" - контент посылается браузеру до header/cookie.

Возможный дубликат вопроса Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?

Ну для начала надо читать логи....если в логах ничего нет - включить отображение ошибок и смотреть. Но скорее всего "void" прав
